# Resolve all example.com/page links to page.html files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to have my server get requests for links like `example.com/page` and then have that resolve to `example.html` or `example.php` inside that directory?

Currently, I am getting a 404 error when a page of mine is requested. The page is in the directory as `page.html`. When I navigate to `example.com/page`, I get the 404. Wouldn't it automatically check for `page.html`? If not, what can I do to make it do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for mod_rewrite: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks, that helps